# ServerEndpoints onMessage "queued" when connected to multiple clients

Tags: java, websocket

I'm working on a websocket implementation that collects data from several (around 10) android clients.
So I have created a classic ServerEndpoint running currently on localhost and on client side an app that opens up a connection to the ServerEndpoint and sends sensor data every 500ms.

The whole thing works fine and on time if I use just one client.
However if I use multiple clients, they send their messages all on time, but the ServerEndpoints onMessage is called at random times. It looks like it "queues" messages from a clients for several seconds, and then fires the onMessage method 5 times in a row. I would need it always on the exact time however. Can I force this?

No errors or exceptions showing up.

This is the very basic server side:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/ServerEndpoint")
public class ServerEndpoint {

static Set<Session> connections = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

@OnOpen
public void handleOpen(Session userSession){
    log("opened session: "+ userSession);
    connections.add(userSession);
}

@OnMessage
public void handleMessage(String message, Session userSession) throws IOException{

    String userName = (String) userSession.getUserProperties().get("username");
    log("received message from: "+ userName+": "+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND)+":"+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)+ "  "+ message );

    ....
}

@OnClose
public void handleClose(Session userSession){
    log("closed session: "+userSession);
    connections.remove(userSession);
}
```

I guess I miss some configuration option of the ServerEndpoint or something. Does someone know what causes this behavior and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright got it. The issue was **Tomcat 7** which has obviously some issues with websockets. Using **Tomcat 8**, it works now without any queues or big delay. Also other minor errors and connection problems were solved by the update and it seems to be much more stable.

Maybe this helps someone facing similar problems.